# Help needed on saving and loading data using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, loading, nsuserdefaults

I am working on a new iPhone app and at the moment I am trying to save and load highscores using NSUserDefaults.
My question is : what code exactly should I use to assign the highscores I have saved to a variable called highscorespointer1, which is a pointer to an NSInteger?
I am currently using the code shown below:

Here i am saving the highscore. Note that the variable highscore1 is of type NSInteger:

```
-(IBAction)saveData{
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:highscore1 forKey:@"H1"];
    [defaults synchronize];
           }
```

And here i am loading the highscore.But i get this warning: "Assignment from incompatible pointer type":

```
highscorepointer1 =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"H1"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInteger:forKey` method sets an `int`, not an `int *`, meaning it sets a value, and not a pointer. Make sure your `highscorepointer1` is an `int`, not an `int *`. It doesn't make sense to save the pointer to the integer anyways, but the actual integer itself should be saved. Hope that Helps!

Comment: and use `integerForKey:` to retrieve an integer rather than `objectForKey:`. At the minute the originating poster is trying to assign a pointer to an object to a pointer to a literal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did what you said and it worked like a charm. I have one more question though: When i was assigning the saved data to a pointer before, i could use this line of code :`if(highscorepointer1 == nil){highscore1 = 0;}` to set highscore to zero if it was the first time the app was executed. Is there something similar i could use now that i am assigning the loaded data directly to  the integer highscore1?

Comment: Actually, by default, if you use `highscore1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"H1"];`, and it has not been set yet, then `highscore1` will equal `0`.